# Error with loading state_dict for ResnetEncoder

Tags: python, resnet

I get this error:
File "C:\Users\d\Desktop\hazy_python\main.py", line 102, in test_simple
encoder.load_state_dict(filtered_dict_enc)

```
File "C:\Users..\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1672, in load_state_dict
self.class.name, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResnetEncoder:
Missing key(s) in state_dict: "encoder.layer1.0.conv3.weight", "encoder.layer1.0.bn3.weight", "encoder.layer1.0.bn3.bias", "encoder.layer1.0.bn3.running_mean", "encoder.layer1.0.bn3.running_var",............
```

I used `strict=False` in
`load_state_dict.  encoder.load_state_dict(filtered_dict_enc,strict=False)`

but nothing happened.